# What particles are released in a particle accelerator?

Tags: particle-physics

When particles like protons collide in a particle accelerator, what kinds of particles are released?

Answer (score 3):

All of them. As long as the accelerated particles have enough energy, they can create any particle when they collide (some particles, like photons, are much easier to create than others). This is why accelerators are used for discovering new particles like the Higgs boson at the Large Hadron Collider.

Answer (score 2):

Proton-proton collisions can release leptons, neutrinos, jets, photons, heavy bosons... The shortest-lived particles can decay before escaping the detector. The others are expected to interact with detector parts  - e.g. for some by energy deposit in calorimeters -, or to go through in the case of weakly interacting particles (neutrinos).